# How To Print From PDA Using Windows CE

Tags: c#-3.0

I Have Project On PDA Device That I Need To print some data In iT.
How i can connect with printer through wirless 
And Programmaticly how can i print the data
I noticed that in the windows CE there is no System.Drawing.Printing Library
So how i can do it in another way
Is there another library to that or what ??
by the way am using C# 3.0
am waiting for your help guys
Thanx alot..